# Getting a red squiglly line under the first cards[0], I dont know what is causing it

Tags: javascript, css

this is minimal js, everything else is commented. I cannot understand why "cards[i]"(first one in the for loop) has a red squiggly line under it, I cannot run any console commands. Please help!

```
    let cards=document.querySelectorAll(".blocks");
    let pic,card,rand;
    let finals = [];
    const count = 10; 
    const max = 9;
    
    for(let k = 0; k < 1000; k++){
      rand = Math.round(Math.random() * max);
    //   !finals.includes(rand) && finals.push(rand)
      if(!finals.includes(rand))
      finals.push(rand);
    }
    finals = finals.slice(0, count)
    setupCards(finals);
    
    function setupCards(arr){
        
        for(let i=0;i<=arr.length;i++){
    ====>cards[i].style.backgroundImage=`url(images/${arr[i]}.jpg)`;
        // cards[i].style.transform="rotateY(180deg)";
        // cards[i].style.backgroundImage="url(images/back6.jpg)";             
     }
}
```

Comment: `i<=arr.length` indicates an off-by-one error; see [What is an off-by-one error and how do I fix it?](/q/2939869/4642212). Another thing: is your `<script>` _above_ your HTML with no `defer` attribute and no `DOMContentLoaded` or `load` listener and is not `type="module"`? See [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as `getElementById` not find the element?](/q/14028959/4642212).

Comment: Please share the corresponding HTML, CSS code.

Answer (score 1):

In this condition test:

```
for(let i=0;i<=arr.length;i++){
```

you are letting the i go from zero (which is the index of the first element) to the length of the array (which gets you to the last plus 1 element - which doesn't exist).

Try:

```
  for(let i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the solution, that was the case. fixed now.